# Renaming files with batch file by "substring" part of the file name

Tags: windows-10, batch-rename

I have loads of files that I want to rename using a batch file, they are music files in this case and start with artist name, album then song number an finally the song name.

I want, if possible without installing any package, to rename the files by removing the artist and album name.

Such as changing:

> Nahko And Medicine For The People - HOKA - 15 Build A Bridge.wav

to

> 15 Build A Bridge.wav

### First thought:

Is it possible to recognise a char as a digit? if so then substring the name from the digit to the end?

### Alternatively

Check the common substring on other files and remove it.

In above example the common substring would be:

> Nahko And Medicine For The People - HOKA -

**Note:** *If the album only has 9 music's I dont mind removing a possible 0 from 09 but hopefully this wouldn't remove the 0 if there are more than 10 since I want the numbers to order the songs in order and music 2 would be after music 19 in such situation*

Comment: Welcome to SU!  Take the [site tour](https://superuser.com/tour) & familiarize yourself with how SU operates.  Also, see [How to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)  including thoroughly [researching before asking and sharing what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Have%20you%20thoroughly%20searched%20for%20an%20answer%20before%20asking%20your%20question%3F%20Sharing%20your%20research%20helps%20everyone.%20Tell%20us%20what%20you%20found%20and%20why%20it%20didn%E2%80%99t%20meet%20your%20

Comment: Better give good examples input files and expected renamed files

Comment: I have given that..

Comment: Not clear enough

Comment: not clear? I give the exact name of a file and an exact expected name after renaming, (as you asked in the comment) and even say 2 ways I think could be used to change the name. If this would be a language I am familiar I could do the change but since I am not so familiar with batch language I am asking if its possible to do such things.

Comment: One problem you are going to encounter is if using batch, it will barf when you come across ANY filename that contains an ampersand (like hall & oats, echo & the bunnymen, or Nahko & Medicine For The People).  I am a lover of batch but when it barfs, you might know why.  Batch is not a good language for string parsing.  Sure, you can do it, but it is going to hurt.

Comment: Its funny that I just finish solving this riddle, and I encountered that issue, solved by manipulating the name within quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Change `C:\Temp` to folder with your songs and run this in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp" -Recurse -Include "*.wav" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.*\b(\d+.*)','$1' }
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I am making a batch file, this syntax cant be used in regular cmd?
I have several folders, and i can access all music files, i just want to understand how to manipulate the string with the name.

Comment: This is powershell script. It could not be executed in cmd/batch directly, but you can either create not `.bat`, but `.ps1` file, or execute this script like so: `powershell -Command "  Get-ChildItem -Path ""C:\Temp"" ... "` (all double quotes in original command should be doubled)

Comment: Yes, although not IN batch, comes installed with windows and can be run FROM batch.  I approve.

Comment: I have solved the issue in the regular .bat, posted an answer here, but i am curious about powershell and i will try this approach one day since is not the first time its recommended over simple cmd. anyway thanks for your help

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, change `C:\Temp` refers to the fact, that in my snippet files renamed in `C:\Temp`, but OP most likely has songs in some other folder.

Comment: thanks for clarifying.  I get it now. duhhhh...

Answer (score 1):

This is along the lines of what I was looking for:

- recognise a digit to separate a string in two,
- keep it simple without dependencies and external tools.

the following block is the relevant excerpt from the script, where `%%c` is the full name of the song.

```bash
::with delayed expation enabled
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::divide the full name into two tokens at the first digit
for /f "tokens=2,* delims=-" %%a in ('echo "%%c" ^| findstr /r "^[0-9]*"') do (
      set name=%%b 
)
rename "%%c" "!name:~0,-3!"
```

*Note: I dont fully understand why I had two whitespace or invisible char at the end of the file name requiring the removal of two characters from the result (the third is to remove the `"` leftover)*

### Example:

> Nahko And Medicine For The People - HOKA - 19 The Wolves Have Returned (feat. Trevor Hall, Xavier Rudd, Leah Song & Joseph).wav

### Result

> 19 The Wolves Have Returned (feat. Trevor Hall, Xavier Rudd, Leah Song & Joseph).wav

Answer (score -1):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
$ rename 's/.*\b(\d+.*)/$1/' ./*.wav
$ ls
15 Build A Bridge.wav
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |
| `(` | group and capture to $1: |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of $1 |

Comment: but here you are assuming i write each name of file and each wanted name? 
i edited the question btw.

Comment: Post edited to work on all `*.wav`

Comment: what does this mean `s/.*\b(\d+.*)/$1/` ? is it checking for digits in the name?
And do I need to install `Perl's rename` ?

Comment: Yes, `\d` is to match digits. And yes, you have to install it. Which OS?

Comment: I am on windows 10, although I didn't specify on the question I would like to keep it as simple as possible (not requiring additional installs) but seems neat solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75214132/how-to-use-file-rename-aka-perls-rename-in-windows/75214133#75214133

Comment: as I mentioned i am looking for a solution, if possible without installing any package

Comment: So next time, add the proper tags

Comment: but that seems clear and simple enough, if I cant find a way to do it "vanilla" I will try this way.

Comment: what tag should I use? beyond the `windows-10` and `batch-rename` that are currently in?

Comment: `windows-10` came after I asked which OS you run. You should be clear at the bebinning and not waste time for people to make response if it's not what you expected

Comment: look your answer didn't change because the OS and I dont know why you are making such an issue and down voting, it was requested the OS I added the OS . the rest of the comments you made to the question i didn't quite understand where they came from. You did answer right to the question at first, so it was clear, I just didnt realize there could be external dependencies if i had known i would say on question from start. now after knowing i edited and its on the question.

Comment: I would guess that down voting is either because of rudeness in the comments or that perl is no longer really a thing.. especially on Windows.